# Приложение создающее другое приложение

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, файлы, компилятор

Приветствую. Не знаю в какую сторону копать и возможно ли такое вообще. Суть задачи такова : есть приложение написанное на c# в windowsforms. В приложении пользователь задает некоторые параметры, указывает пути к картинке ect и после выполнения всех настроек родительское приложение собирает в папке рядом с собой еще одно exe программу но значительно урезанную согласно установкам пользователя. Можно ли такое сделать если да то в какую сторону рыть, чем гугол мучать ?

Comment: а через конфигурацию не вариант это сделать? При первом запуске предоставляем интерфейс для настройки, при последующих запускаем интерфейс согласно настройкам. Настройки можно в реестр упрятать если просто файл не подходит или вообще в БД, если программа должна работать с БД. И ничего пересобирать не придется

Comment: Это было бы отличным решением, но программа работает с несколькими пользователями на разных ПК. Тот кто выполняет роль админа настраивает функционал под каждого пользователя отдельно и пользователь никак не может изменить настройки своего экземпляра. А любые изменения происходят через администратора, который удаляет старую версию и передает пользователю новую с новыми возможностями. Кажется такой процесс называется "динамической компиляцией" ? Когда exe может компилировать новый ехе.

Comment: Не проще передавать защищённый контрольной суммой конфигурационный файл, в котором определены разрешённые функции? плюс сверка по, скажем, имени станции и учётной записи... класть в предопределённое место профиля.

Comment: @Akina Возможно, но потенциального заказчика интересует именно такой вариант как я описал. Если такое вообще невозможно то буду искать альтернативы.

Comment: Тогда тем более конфиг через БД сделать, у нас сейчас похожий вариант используется, интерфейс приложения завязан на роли пользователя прописанные в БД. Для изменения функционала для пользователя можно вообще никуда не ходить, роль изменил и все. С этим даже техподдержка справляется, админ не нужен

Comment: Можно, например, с помощью [CSharpCodeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) компилировать launcher - небольшую программку, которая будет стартовать основное приложение с нужными настройками.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а сам процесс называется динамической компиляцией ?

Comment: Да, можно и рантайм exe генерировать, при желании (никто не мешает вам запускать csc.exe из вашего процесса), но вам точно нужен такой микроскоп для ваших гвоздей? Что вам мешает разбить ваш функционал на мелкие dll, а потом собирать их в папке? При желании вы можете все необходимые модули собрать в один exe (ilmerge в помощь).

Comment: @PrimusSingularis csc.exe строит из командной строки? А просто пользовательским интерфейсом не обойтись ?

Comment: @Сергей - `CSharpCodeProvider` это и есть интерфейс к csc.exe. И Visual Studio тоже интерфейс к нему же.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Благодарю, теперь ясно куда копать. В принципе вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашел небольшой пример по теме. Если кому будет интересно вот код с динамической компиляцией (exe создается из exe) :

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace ConsoleCompiler {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Source code для компиляции 
            string source =
            @" namespace Foo 
            {
                public class Bar
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        Bar.SayHello();
                        System.Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                    public static void SayHello()
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
                    }
                }
            }";

            // Настройки компиляции 
            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
            };
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
            { OutputAssembly = "D:\\Foo.EXE", GenerateExecutable = true };

            // Компиляция 
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            // Выводим информацию об ошибках 
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Errors: {0}", results.Errors.Count);
            foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0}", err.ErrorText);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Сам вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: зачем закрывать хороший вопрос, просто примите свой же ответ когда пройдет время карантина и пусть остается, не думаю что вы последний кому это может пригодиться =)

Answer (score 2):

Компиляция нового приложения - довольно тяжелый вариант, из разряда "из пушки по воробьям". Особенно "весело" в такой программе будет экранировать константы в коде...

Можно поступить проще.

Для начала, можно просто отдавать копировать текущую программу (или лежащую рядом), но с измененным конфигом. Это намного проще всех остальных вариантов.

Если же принципиально нужно забить настройки в код, то можно сделать вот так:

1. Готовим библиотеку с точкой входа, которая будет принимать все нужные настройки:

   ```
   public sealed class Program
   {
       public string Foo { get; set; }
       public int Bar { get; set; }

       public void Run()
       {
            // ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Создаем выражение на создание объекта с зашитыми настройками:

   ```
   var configExpr = Expression.MemberInit(
       Expression.New(typeof(Program)),
       Expression.Bind(typeof(Program).GetProperty("Foo"), Expression.Constant("Hello, world!")),
       Expression.Bind(typeof(Program).GetProperty("Bar"), Expression.Constant(42)));
   ```
3. Создаем программу-загрузчик через Reflection.Emit:

   ```
   var assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Loader"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
   var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Main", "Loader.exe");
   var type = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Loader", TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Sealed);
   var method = type.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Static);
   Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(configExpr, "Run", null)).CompileToMethod(method);
   type.CreateType();
   assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(method, PEFileKinds.WindowApplication);
   assemblyBuilder.Save("Loader.exe");
   ```

Как видно, код получился заметно короче чем вариант с использованием CodeDOM. И безопаснее.